# @input event in customized component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<MyComponent
   v-model="myProp"
   @input="myMethod"
/>
```

In Vue, I can understand if I use input event inside a input tag.
Can't understand the usage of input event in a customized component,but without defining it.
Couldn't find any reference from Vue doc, either.

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for these:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

You are binding `myMethod()` to the 'input' event, which is raised by calling `this.$emit('input')` from within MyCompnent.vue.

Comment: Thanks, that's true. Do you think we should avoid naming a customized event 'input'? Sometimes it is confusing, and lead people to believe it is an event provided by Vue.

Comment: Sorry, I think the reason is that v-model is the sugar syntax of @input and :value, so the input event is provided by Vue by default